# Show one random icon on page load

Tags: javascript, random, font-awesome

How do I show one random icon on page load with js? Below is the HTML code I have:

```
<span>
  <i class="fa fa-trash-o" id="icon-one"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-frown-o" id="icon-two"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down" id="icon-three"></i>
</span>
```

I need to show only one of the three icons.

Comment: Have you put any effort into trying to solve this yourself?

Comment: you can use php rand() function, then base upon return between 3 options hide/show.

Answer (score 2):

My HTML would be

```
<span id = "mySpan"></span>
```

You can do this using javascript

```
var myRand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
var randString = '';

if(myRand == 1) 
    randString = 'one';
else if(myRand == 2) 
    randString = 'two';
else if(myRand == 3) 
    randString = 'three';

var ele = document.createElement("div");
ele.setAttribute("id","icon-"+randString );
document.getElementById("mySpan").appendChild(ele);
```

Well , this assumes that your ids have the icon and not the classes

Answer (score 2):

```
<span>
  <i class="fa fa-trash-o" style="display: none;" id="icon-one"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-frown-o" style="display: none;" id="icon-two"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down" style="display: none;" id="icon-three"></i>
</span>

var icons = [ 'icon-one', 'icon-two', 'icon-three' ],
    icon = icons[Math.floor(Math.random()*icons.length)];

$( '#' + icon ).show();
```

This should work if you are using jquery.

Answer (score 2):

use this function to get a random no in range(min, max)

```
  function getRandomArbitary (min, max) {
        return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
    }
```

and use appropriately to show the tag  hide other wise

such as 
js

```
var r =  function getRandomArbitary (1, 3);

var eleCategory = document.getElementById("main_div");
var eleChild = eleCategory.childNodes;
for( i = 0 , i<eleChild.length; i++ ){
    if(i==r){
        eleChild[ i ].style.display='block';
    }
    else
    {
        eleChild[ i ].style.display='none';
     }
}
```

html

```
<span id="main_div">
  <i class="fa fa-trash-o" id="icon-one"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-frown-o" id="icon-two"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-down" id="icon-three"></i>
</span>
```

Comment: You were faster than me! Why use `childNodes` instead of `children`?

Comment: @A1rPun children is a property of the element and children would be type of element. whereas childNodes are the child elements in given element.

Comment: `.children` returns a `HTMLCollection` with only HTML elements (no text nodes). What I'm trying to say is the above code won't work ^^. Try it yourself. I +1 because it IS the solution ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can use java script here. So if there are only three icons one , two and three.

use random function to generate a number between one two and three

```
var x= Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1); 
if (x==1)
{
//fetch the div id = "icon-one" and display
}
else if (x==2)
{
//fetch the div id = "icon-two" and display
}
else
{
//fetch the div id = "icon-three" and display
}
```

Although this will work way better if you can rename your id's two icon1,icon2 and so on
it will just be this then :

```
var x= Math.floor((Math.random()*3)+1); 
var icon = "icon";
var id = icon.concat(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple work woth using `jQuery`.

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f9kmm/2/)

Comment: jup I totally should do that :D Brain afk